# Most JS file not working all of a sudden

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I think I'm losing my mind. I'm in a MVC solution using Visual Studio 2017, I've been building this app for a long time, it was working yesterday, but today, many javascript files are not working and failing on things that were working...

i.e.:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at select2.full.js:14
    at select2.full.js:19
```

Code of select2.full.js, I include it here but I changed nothing and was working before:

```
/*!
 * Select2 4.0.3
 * https://select2.github.io
 *
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/LICENSE.md
 */
(function (factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node/CommonJS
    factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    // Browser globals
   factory(jQuery);
 }
```

}(function (jQuery) {

```
fr.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'define' of undefined
    at fr.js:3
    at fr.js:3

jquery.contextMenu.js:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at jquery.contextMenu.js:24
    at jquery.contextMenu.js:29

bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:42 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:42
    at bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:53

lada.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at lada.min.js:2
    at lada.min.js:2
```

I'm using the bundle feature of MVC.

I've read that the require need require.js, I've never had it in the project, I don't have node.js and never used it... I'm just baffled why my code is doing that this morning...

Comment: Have you or some recently added library added a global variable called `exports`? That would make the script think that it's being run on Node. `console.log(exports)`?

Comment: Seems to be some kind of problem like that! If i do console.log(exports) in the browser console:

console.log(exports)
VM1585:1 Object__esModule: truedefault: d(t)__proto__: Object

Comment: How Do I find the culprit?

Comment: Nevermind, found it, retina.min.js

Comment: @JJJ If you want to put your comment in an answer so I can mark it as the answer!